# How to Wrap all DIVs after or before specific DIVs using javascript or MooTools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

What I am trying to do is trying to wrap all DIVs after or before some specific DIVs.

here is the code:

```
<div class="heading">Heading one</div>
<div>question one</div>
<div>question two</div>
<div>question three</div>
<div class="heading">Heading two</div>
<div>question one</div>
<div>question two</div>
<div>question three</div>
<div>question four</div>
<div>question five</div>
<div>question six</div>
<div class="heading">Heading three</div>
<div>question one</div>
<div>question two</div>
```

so the questions within these heading DIVs I want to wrap them dynamically so if questions may be more or less for any heading will automatically wrap inside another div and will assign the ids or classes to them to show and hide.

Want to do it dynamically using JavaScript or mootools:

Remember that questions may vary as user adds from the Admin Panel against every heading.

Edit: Please also remember that Headings may also be vary may be more headings can be added by user and every heading can contain questions.

```
<div class="heading">Heading one</div>
<div id='one'>
    <div>question one</div>
    <div>question two</div>
    <div>question three</div>
</div>
<div class="heading">Heading two</div>
<div id='two'>
    <div>question one</div>
    <div>question two</div>
    <div>question three</div>
    <div>question four</div>
    <div>question five</div>
    <div>question six</div>
</div>
<div class="heading">Heading three</div>
<div id='three'>
    <div>question one</div>
    <div>question two</div>
</div>
```

Please let me if you think the question is not good in comments so that if you rate down as bad I will not be able to ask more questions.

Thanks.

Comment: can't you use jQyery for this, that will make it better.

Comment: No, I can't use jQuery. but you can tell me the solution in jQuery.

Comment: Side note: wrap headings in heading tags, not div tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var newParent, id = 1;
$$('div').each(function (element) {
    if (element.hasClass('heading')) {
        newParent = new Element('div[id=heading_' + id + ']').inject(element, 'after');
        id++;
    } else {
        newParent.wraps(element);
    }
});
```

#### Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/nudmwcaf/)

Or to make it without globals:

```
$$('div').each(function (element) {
    if (element.hasClass('heading')) {
        var id = $$('div[id^=heading_').length + 1;
        var newParent = new Element('div[id=heading_' + id + ']').inject(element, 'after');
    } else {
        element.getPrevious().wraps(element);
    }
});
```

#### Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/nudmwcaf/2/)

The **[.wraps()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:wraps)** method is the key here.

Comment: Great can we avoid the very last question stop warping it so that it is the submit button like in last heading whatever be the last heading 
<div class="heading">Heading three</div>

<div>question one</div>

<div>question two</div> ---> can we stop this element to be wrapped?

Comment: @M3Dev, yes, but please add the HTML for that part so I can answer properly.

Comment: just the last question in last heading i.e. <div>question two</div> it should not be wrapped thats all.

Comment: Great but when I try to implement it is saying: Cannot read property 'wraps' of undefined

Comment: @M3Dev then your HTML is not the same as in the question (!). Check my fiddle in last comment, no errors there. That is why I asked for your HTML...

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ymDrn/41/)**

js

```
$('.heading + div').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil(".heading").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
});
```

<s>here it is with different IDs</s>

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ymDrn/42/)**

js

```
var ID = 0;
$('.heading + div').each(function () {
    ID++;
    $(this).nextUntil(".heading").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="content" />').attr('id', 'id' + ID);
});
```

**## Final Demo**

js

```
$('.heading + div').each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".heading").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
    $(element).parent().attr('id', 'id' + index);
});
```

I am using the index and element so the id count starts from 0

Not to effect the last one

**## Demo not to effect last**

js

```
$('.heading:not(:last) + div').each(function (index, element) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".heading").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="content" />');
    $(element).parent().attr('id', 'id' + index);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but can't we assign each wrapper a unique id?

Comment: Yeah, I followed ur question and I am trying to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks :) will accept your answer tomorrow if I found no solution.

Comment: Sorry you did something wrong I think I want to have to unique ids for content div you added not for its child. like <div class="content" id="unique id for every div" ></div>

Comment: yes this solves but can we also avoid warping the very last question which is at the end. i.e. <div>question two</div> very last

Comment: Yes I see.Please I just want to stop wrapping the last element not the whole heading just the last question.

Comment: Please don't answer with jQuery on a MooTools question.

Comment: yeah I second you on this, but OP mentioned in comments that "No, I can't use jQuery. but you can tell me the solution in jQuery."

Answer (score 0):

Applying the jquery solution already mentioned to mootools, you'd use the "GetUntil" method: http://mootools.net/forge/p/element_getuntil. And then wrap using wraps: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:wraps.